# Spring boot JobOperator.stop(executionId) and JobOperator.restart(executionId) behavior

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to make use of Spring batch to deal with batch jobs.
When I try to `stop` a running job using `executionId`, the job is stopped with below entry in `SpringBatchDb.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` table

> '104','3','104','2017-11-27 11:39:10','2017-11-27 11:39:10','2017-11-27 11:39:48','STOPPED','STOPPED','org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException','2017-11-27 11:39:48',NULL

Note that the `STATUS` and `EXIT_CODE` is updated as `STOPPED`. But it throws an exception as, `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [testJob] was registered
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:66)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.restart(SimpleJobOperator.java:275)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44ee6049.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$318ff269.restart(<generated>)
at com.test.mypackage.batch.dao.BatchJobDaoImpl.restartJobExecution(BatchJobDaoImpl.java:62)` .

When I attempt to restart the same job using executionId, it fails to start and gives same exception (shown above).

My Code is pretty simple,

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private JobOperator jobOperator;
@Override
public Long stopRunningExecution(Long executionId) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionNotRunningException {
    jobOperator.stop(executionId);
    return executionId;
}
@Override
public Long restartJobExecution(long executionId) throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, NoSuchJobExecutionException, NoSuchJobException {
    return jobOperator.restart(executionId);
}
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a similar error but was able to resolve the issue.

The issue is occurring since you have not defined the JobRegistry. If you define the JobRegistry and add it to your JobOperator Bean then the above exception will not happen.

For example:

```
@Bean
public JobRegistry jobRegistry() {
    return new MapJobRegistry();
}

@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry());
    return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
}

@Bean
public JobOperator jobOperator() {
    SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
    jobOperator.setJobExplorer(getJobExplorer());
    jobOperator.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobOperator.setJobLauncher(getJobLauncher());
    jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry());

    return jobOperator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt how you retrieve execution Id. Try accepting StepExecution in place of id and call:

```
jobOperator.stop(stepExecution.getJobExecutionId());
```

Don't know if it can be useful in your case.